# checking when youtube video is dismissed from full screen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have a UIWebView in which sometimes inside of that it has a youtube player for videos. Users can see the video in full screen as well. However the issue is that when the user sees the video in full screen, then rotates it, it doesn't call willAnimateToInterfaceOrientation. So I am planning on calling this manually. The question is how do I check whenever someone has dismissed the youtube video?

Answer (score 0):

Try registering yourself for `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification` in `viewDidLoad`

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
               selector:@selector(didRotate:)
               name:@"UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification" object:nil];

- (void) didRotate:(NSNotification *)notification{  
UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];

  //Handle rotation 

}
```